# Unable to get ConEmu task file to work

Tags: conemu

I'm trying to get ConEmu to start up with two tabs, each with their own initial path, and I am completely unable to do so. There is **a lot** of ConEmu information out there, but I just can;'t get this to work.

I've changed my shortcut to ConEmu to be as follows:

`"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" -run @C:\Users\rhewitt\Documents\conemu_startlist.txt`

and the `conemu_startlist.txt` file contains the following (on one line):

`cmd /k color 4C -cur_console:t:"cmd":d:"C:\Users\rhewitt" ^|^|^| cmd /k color 5D -cur_console:t:"git":d:"C:\Users\rhewitt\CONFIG\repos"`

Whenever I start ConEmu, I get a single tab called "git" with the following text in it:

```
Sets the default console foreground and background colors.

COLOR [attr]

attr        Specifies color attribute of console output

Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first
corresponds to the background; the second the foreground.  Each digit
can be any of the following values:

0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White

If no argument is given, this command restores the color to what it was
when CMD.EXE started.  This value either comes from the current console
window, the /T command line switch or from the DefaultColor registry
value.

The COLOR command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if an attempt is made to execute
the COLOR command with a foreground and background color that are the
same.

Example: "COLOR fc" produces light red on bright white

C:\Users\rhewitt\CONFIG\repos>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I looked, but I can't find anything obvious...

Comment: Task file must not contain `^|^|^|`. Why did you add this? One line - one console!

Comment: @Maximus that solved it! Thanks. I guess I got confused about inline runlist and startlist as opposed to a startlist file. Or something. I've been using ConEmu for years, but never tried using a startlist file before.